# How to achive pagination for array of array in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am sure this is not duplicate question, please read completely and share your ideas.

I am getting data from server,on calling API(example [API1](http://pastie.org/10620514)) first time , I am getting 20 records , based on “events” count.

In Jan 5 events, in Feb 6 events, March 5 events ,Apr 8 events

But API not returning all the events of April in first call as I have to retrieve only 20 records at a time.

I second time calling API, I am getting remaining records of April month(example [API2](http://pastie.org/10620517)).

I have to add remaining three records to previous array to show all the April months events under same section.

I am creating a view based on the event’s array and sub viewing to the cell content, I didn't take any custom cell because of critical UI design as shown below.

[image]

In the above image, Dec 2016 created twice, as first few records comes in first call of API and next few records comes in second API call.

How do I achieve this..?

Answer (score 0):

You store an array somewhere with the meaning "this is the data that I currently know about". Your tableview uses this array as its source for all its operation.

When more data arrives, you do the following *on the main thread*: Modify the array so that it contains the new data, then call reloadData for the view that is modified.

Now if you get data for the month april twice, then the "modify the array" is slightly more complicated: For every month arriving, you check if that month is already there; that month would have an array of data associated with it, so you add the new data to that array. If the month isn't there already, you add a new month.